# Mark checkbox in all companies AX2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I added a checkbox in PurchParameters table which name is setExchRateVal and I want to mark true this field in my all companies without sql operations.

How can i do this in AX with job?

I tried this but it's not done,

```
PurchParameters purchParameters ;

while select forUpdate crossCompany purchParameters
{
    purchParameters.setExchRateVal = NoYes::Yes;
    purchParameters.update();
    //info(strFmt("%1 - %2", purchParameters.SetExchRateVal, purchParameters.dataAreaId));
}
```

AX ERROR :
Update operations are not allowed across companies.

Comment: What code have you tried? Any sample?

Comment: Check out [crossCompany/changeCompany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/cross-company-data-modification-using-x) and the [DataArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics/ax-2012/reference/gg887932(v=ax.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) table.

Comment: Thank you @FH-Inway, i used changeCompany in while statement and it's done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is clear. You can't do `crossCompany` and `updates` in the same select query. `Method 2` below is closer to what you're doing. When updating parameter tables, it can be done a few ways because of the `Key` on the table.

See below:

```cs
PurchParameters purchParametersUpdate;
PurchParameters purchParametersSeek;
DataArea        dataArea;

// Method 1
ttsBegin;
while select dataArea
{
    changeCompany(dataArea.id)
    {
        purchParametersUpdate = PurchParameters::find(true);
        purchParametersUpdate.setExchRateVal = NoYes::Yes;
        purchParametersUpdate.update();
    }
}
ttsCommit;


// Method 2
ttsBegin;
while select crossCompany purchParametersSeek
{
    purchParametersUpdate = null;

    select firstOnly forUpdate purchParametersUpdate
        where purchParametersUpdate.RecId == purchParametersSeek.RecId;

    if (purchParametersUpdate)
    {
        //purchParametersUpdate.setExchRateVal = NoYes::Yes;
        purchParametersUpdate.update();
    }
}
ttsCommit;

info("Done");
```

Comment: Also see this answer for an approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899654/4509

Comment: thank you very mıuch for all answers. I learned more than one way